# Multiple GCE instances with one root persistent disk

Tags: cloud, google-compute-engine

I finally got into Google Compute Engine today!  I am confused about one point and I fear that my gut instinct is correct but I wanted to make sure.  I was fooling around with the f1-micro instance because I am cheap and don't want to accidentally wind up with a several hundred dollar bill (thanks Windows Azure!) and these instances do not have a scratch disk, instead you have to create a persistent disk and use it as a root disk to boot off of.  That's fine, but when you create the disk automatically it creates a 10GB disk.  I read that you can attach more than one instance to a persistent disk but that the disk must be read only mode.  Since it doesn't make much sense to have a boot disk be read only, I don't think it's going to be possible to attach multiple instances to a root disk.  I tried and it the result was an error.    The error was about creating multiple instances of a compute instance so I might have had the command wrong.  Does anyone know if it is possible to create a root persistent disk and then attach multiple compute instances to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a separate root persistent disk for each running instance. You can use [snapshots](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/disks#snapshots) to create additional copies of an existing persistent disk.

Comment: Thanks Brian.  But I assume that the root persistent disk does not have to be a minimum of 10GB?  I am trying to keep costs down while experimenting.  If I spin up a 10 GB disk, keep it for an hour, delete it, and then spin up another 10 GB disk, and keep it for an hour, will I be charged for 20GB?

Comment: Persistent disk pricing is averaged over the whole month, so in your example it would be: ((10GB * 2 hours) / # of hours in the month) * current price per GB/month.
Current prices here:
https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/pricing#persistentdisk

Comment: Also, the minimum size of root persistent disks depends on the size of the original image. Most of the current provided images are approximately 10GB.

Comment: Excellent!  I really like the pricing model!  This is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In theory you could boot from a read-only device with a small read-write overlayfs that will absorb the writes. This is similar to how you boot a physical host from a USB drive.